# Build protocol buffers for Python with Bazel

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel

Is this possible? AFAICT there's no built-in `py_proto_library` rule, and trying to use my own `genrule` like:

```
genrule(
  name = "my_proto",
  srcs = ["my.proto"],
  outs = ["my_pb2.py", "my_pb2_grpc.py"],
  cmd = "python -m grpc_tools.protoc --python_out=$(@D) --grpc_python_out=$(@D) $<"
)
```

in the `deps` of a `py_binary` fails with `'//:my_proto' does not have mandatory provider 'py'.`

Comment: [Issue 8079](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8079) is the issue to watch for formal support within gRPC itself.

Answer (score 3):

It should work fine rolling your own proto files like you're doing, you just need to add them to the `srcs` (not `deps`) of your `py_binary`.

`deps` are only for `py_library`s (you could also wrap your `.py` in a `py_library` if you preferred and then have the binary depend on that).

Comment: Oh, interesting, I didn't realize rules could go in the `srcs` attribute, I thought it had to be source files. What's the difference between `srcs` and `deps` here?

Comment: `srcs` is a list of Python sources (files with a .py extension), so outputs from your genrule qualify. `deps` are a list of `py_library`s, little "package" of information.  For example, say you had a library that read a .csv file. You could create a py_library with .py sources and a data dependency on that .csv file and then, if the py_binary depended on that library, it would be able to find out about that .csv file, too.